# How to make 5 column row in zurb 5 foundation

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I want to have a 5 column in `row` and only 1 column for small devices screens with less then 480px width.

I am new to zurb foundation and still learning about it.

fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/V7TuY/1/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-6 medium-3 large-3 columns">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/480x600&text=[img 1]" />
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="small-6 medium-3 large-3 columns">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/480x600&text=[img 2]" />
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="small-6 medium-3 large-3 columns">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/480x600&text=[img 3]" />
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="small-6 medium-3 large-3 columns">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/480x600&text=[img 4]" />
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="small-6 medium-3 large-3 columns">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/480x600&text=[img 5]" />
        <p></p>
    </div>
```

Is it better to this kind of thing with columns or list `ul li`

Answer (score 18):

[The foundation grid is based on 12 "units" per row](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html).  In your example you have 5 `<div>` with classes `medium-3` and `large-3` = 15 units per row.  Foundation will manage to fit the first 4 in (4 * 3 = 12 units), and then the fifth will be pushed to the line below.

One idea to fit in your 5 items, is to give everything a `medium-2` width (10 units), and offset the row by one `unit` on the left (class [`medium-offset-1` on first element](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html#offsets)) and tell Foundation that the fifth element is the last in your row (with class [`end` on the last element](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html#incomplete-rows)).

For example:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="small-12 medium-2 medium-offset-1 columns">   
    <img src="http://placehold.it/480x600&text=[img 1]"/>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-2 columns">   
    <img src="http://placehold.it/480x600&text=[img 1]"/>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-2 columns">   
    <img src="http://placehold.it/480x600&text=[img 1]"/>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-2 columns">   
    <img src="http://placehold.it/480x600&text=[img 1]"/>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-2 columns end">   
    <img src="http://placehold.it/480x600&text=[img 1]"/>
  </div>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V7TuY/4/

The point of the `medium-offset-1` is to centre the content (after a fashion): you have 10 units to fit into a possible 12.  Offsetting by one, and using `end` will leave you with a 1 unit gap on each side of your content.  However, if you want it to sit to the left of your page just remove the `medium-offset-1` class from the example above.

Note - You really only need the `medium-2` and `medium-offset-2` here as by default this applies to `large` grids too, unless overriden by classes `large-*` or `large-offset-*`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. what if i do it this way http://jsfiddle.net/TUHdL/2/. is this approach better as in this case i dont have to add offset... and image appear slightly bigger. reference http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html

Comment: Yes - it might look better, depending on your content.  I would experiment with both methods!

Comment: …or set the column number to something that is dividable by five.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker Also you can drop `small-12` because they are 12 by the default.

Answer (score 13):

Maybe I am a little late to the party, but if you are using scss, you can achieve this easily.

```
.col5-unit{
  @include grid-column(2.4); // (12/5 = 2.4)
}
```

Then in your html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col5-unit"> Column 1 </div>
  <div class="col5-unit"> Column 2 </div>
  <div class="col5-unit"> Column 3 </div>
  <div class="col5-unit"> Column 4 </div>
  <div class="col5-unit"> Column 5 </div>
</div>
```

Actually you can have any number of column you need. Just pass the argument `(12/[required number of column])`

Comment: This is maybe not the right answer due to not knowing if the OP is using .scss but it helped me immensely. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/PZuLm/

```
<div class="row">   
        <div class="small-12 medium-2 medium-offset-1  columns">   
          <img src="http://placehold.it/480x600&text=[img 1]"/>
        </div>     
        <div class="small-12 medium-2 columns">
           <img src="http://placehold.it/480x600&text=[img 2]"/>         
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 medium-2 columns">  
           <img src="http://placehold.it/480x600&text=[img 3]"/>    
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 medium-2 columns">    
           <img src="http://placehold.it/480x600&text=[img 4]"/>
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 medium-2 medium-pull-1 columns">    
           <img src="http://placehold.it/480x600&text=[img 5]"/> 
        </div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try a block grid: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html. I added this to your JSFiddle:

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-1 medium-block-grid-5 large-block-grid-5">
<li><!-- Your content goes here -->1</li>
<li><!-- Your content goes here -->2</li>
<li><!-- Your content goes here -->2</li> 
<li><!-- Your content goes here -->4</li>
<li><!-- Your content goes here -->5</li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi sure! Guess my addition to the fiddle was removed but here is the block grid fiddle link for the example above: http://jsfiddle.net/7hxspjm2/

Comment: Thanks, This even show 5 blocks for small screen it should show one block for small screen such as 480px & below.

Comment: Yes it does! Which is why I think this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the sass version, there is a variable called **$total-columns** in **_settings.scss**. This is set to 12 by default. You can change this to 10 and then use html such as:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="small-10 medium-2 large-2 columns">   
    <img src="http://placehold.it/480x600&text=[img 1]"/>
  </div>
  <div class="small-10 medium-2 large-2 columns">   
    <img src="http://placehold.it/480x600&text=[img 1]"/>
  </div>
  <div class="small-10 medium-2 large-2 columns">   
    <img src="http://placehold.it/480x600&text=[img 1]"/>
  </div>
  <div class="small-10 medium-2 large-2 columns">   
    <img src="http://placehold.it/480x600&text=[img 1]"/>
  </div>
  <div class="small-10 medium-2 large-2 columns">   
    <img src="http://placehold.it/480x600&text=[img 1]"/>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can extend the idea Gavin put forth further to create a full mixin that creates another whole grid you can use, within the regular system. just do something like:

```
.alternative_grid {
  $total-columns:10;
  @include grid-row();
  @include grid-html-classes($size:large);
  $total-columns:10;
}
```

then append the footer_grid class to your row, and you'll be able to use both a 12 grid overalll (since it's standard) and a 10 grid for special cases.

Comment: could you please provide an example (maybe a jsfiddle) of this? it's not very clear how to use this technique